# String reduction

Tags: string, algorithm

May be it's a well-known problem by now :
 consider any string S , containing only 3 characters (a,b,c). You can do this reduction operation on these strings : "replace two consecutive distinct characters by the 3rd one like 'ab' can be replace by 'c' and 'ac' cab be by 'b'." how much we can reduce by this operation?

the answer is always either (1,2,string.length) .

string.length iff all characters are same,
2 iff count(a) = count(b) = count(c) in S.
1 otherwise.
but i am not able to prove it .

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: http://tristan-interview.blogspot.in/2012/03/string-reduction.html

Answer (score 0):

You prove this type of claim by induction on the length of *S*.

But you have to get the claim right, and you haven't here. Your claim is

> the answer is |*S*| if all characters are same, 2 if count(a) = count(b) = count(c) in *S*, and 1 otherwise.

Consider the string `aabb`. Your claim says that this can be reduced to length 1, but in fact it can only be reduced to length 2: the possible reduction sequences are `aabb` → `acb` → `bb` and `aabb` → `acb` → `aa`.

Get the claim right and you should be able to complete the proof.